# System.NotSupportedException: The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository

I'm getting error after this join.
Normal linq query working fine.
I'm using database first approach.

When I'm collecting data from more than one table its throwing exception. 
The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.

```
public partial class EfRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly WebEntities _context;
    private IDbSet<T> _entities;

    public EfRepository(WebEntities context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> Table
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Entities;
        }
    }

    protected virtual IDbSet<T> Entities
    {
        get
        {
            if (_entities == null)
                _entities = _context.Set<T>();
            return _entities;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Query on Service.cs

```
var query = from rc in _FAQRepository.Table
                     join r in _FAQCategoryRepository.Table on rc.FAQCategoryID equals r.FAQCategoryID
                     select rc;
        return query.ToList();
```

Initialization

```
#region "FIELDS"
    private readonly IRepository<tblFAQ> _FAQRepository;
    private readonly IRepository<tblFAQCategory> _FAQCategoryRepository;
    #endregion

    #region "CONSTRUCTOR"
    public FAQService(IRepository<tblFAQ> FAQRepository, 
        IRepository<tblFAQCategory> FAQCategoryRepository)
    {
        this._FAQRepository = FAQRepository;
        this._FAQCategoryRepository = FAQCategoryRepository;
    }
    #endregion
```

Register Services..

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {

        kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(EfRepository<>));
        kernel.Bind<WebEntities>().To<WebEntities>();
        kernel.Bind<PT.Services.FAQCategory.IFAQCategoryService>().To<PT.Services.FAQCategory.FAQCategoryService>();
        kernel.Bind<PT.Services.FAQ.IFAQService>().To<PT.Services.FAQ.FAQService>();
```

}

Comment: Could you show us how are the respective repositories (`_FAQRepository` and `_FAQCategoryRepository`) initialized?

Comment: I updated question with Initialization.

Comment: That's not initialization - that's just the bit where some already initialized objects are assigned to your local fields.

Comment: I've added service registration. Is this you need?

Comment: yes, much better - though mentioning that you're using NInject would work as well. You need to ensure both repositories share the same context. Not an expert on NI, but I believe using `kerner.Bind<WebEntities>.ToConstant(/*your context*/)` should do the trick.

Comment: WebEntities is the dbcontext.

Comment: `WebEntities` is your context class, you need an instance of your context, at the very least `.ToConstant(new WebEntities())`.

Comment: decPL Please Post your comment as "Answer" so I can mark it answerd.